# Write a value to existing CSV file without prompting user to select csv file

Tags: reactjs, csv, async-await, append, window

i have a code which on selection of region should update the contents of a variable known as csvContent to an existing csv named data.csv.
but currently when i run it prompts the user to select the data.csv and overwrites the existing csv file.

below is the code .

```
        .then(async (result) => {
      const text = result.text?.trim();
      console.log(result.data.text)
      const dataType = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      const csvContent = [result.data.text, dataType, x, y, width, height].join(",");
      console.log(csvContent)
    
      // Get a handle to the existing data.csv file
      const handle = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
        multiple: false,
        types: [{
          description: 'CSV files',
          accept: {
            'text/csv': ['.csv']
          },
        }],
      });
    
      // Open the file in append mode
      const file = await handle[0].getFile();
      const writable = await file.createWritable({ keepExistingData: true });
    
      // Append to the file
      await writable.write(csvContent + "\n");
      await writable.close();
    
      this.setState({ extractedText: result.text });
    });
```

so i am able to see the contents of csvContent variable , but the code prompts selection of data.csv . Is there any way to avoid that and directly append the csvContent value to CSV file

Comment: You can use react-csv library to update values in csv. Get all data from csv and then append data come from api and then replace the file where you get the data

Comment: but when i google , i can't find any example related to that. Since am new to react am not very good in it @MuhammadAhab